# How to delete string in variable

Tags: bash

Good day
how to remove all the variables in the last slash in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="/foo/bar/abcd ef gh"
```

I need to remove: **abcd ef gh**

path /foo/bar/ is always different

Seeking short notation ;-)
thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your $VAR is always a path to a dir/file, you can use this:

```
$ VAR=$(dirname "$VAR")
$ echo $VAR
/foo/bar
```

Update: You can also use parameter substitution in bash:

```
$ echo ${VAR%/*}
/foo/bar
```

Comment: Worth nothing the results are slightly different between dirname and parameter replacement in the case of values like `/foo` or `foo` - dirname turns them into / and ., respectively, while parameter replacement empties the first and leaves the second alone.